# Translate using dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm just trying some code from workbooks and there are different exercises but I wanted to try one with a pre-existing message, I've gotten this far but I can't figure out how to complete it. How would I go about doing this?

```
alphabet = {"A": ".-","B": "-...","C": "-.-.",
            "D": "-..","E": ".","F": "..-.",
            "G": "--.", "H": "....","I": "..",
            "J": ".---","K": "-.-", "L": ".-..",
            "M": "--",  "N": "-.",  "O": "---",
            "P": ".--.","Q": "--.-","R": ".-.",
            "S": "...", "T": "-",   "U": "..-",
            "V": "...-","W": ".--", "X": "-..-",
            "Y": "-.--", "Z": "--.."}

message = ".-- .... . .-. . / .- .-. . / -.-- --- ..-"

for key,val in alphabet.items():
    if message in alphabet:
        print(key)
```

Comment: If you do want to decode a Morse code message, then shouldn't you reverse the dictionary?

Comment: Furthermore you first need to separate the message into separate parts.

Comment: And some letters contain others

Comment: I have saw it done by just leaving the message in, I can change it though if that seems like a better way of doing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reverse your dictionary:

```
alphabet1 = {b:a for a, b in alphabet.items()} 
message = ".-- .... . .-. . / .- .-. . / -.-- --- ..-"
decoded_message = ''.join(alphabet1.get(i, ' ') for i in message.split())
```

Output:

```
'WHERE ARE YOU'
```

Comment: You're missing `message.split()` I think.

Comment: @Ajax1234 I have tried that but it doesn't like the "/" giving out an error

Comment: @PeterToole what does the '/' translate to? An end of sentence?

Comment: @Ajax1234 yeah it it a space so its separating the words

Comment: Thank You @Ajax1234 I had to put in a print(decoded_message) in there to make it work, I don't know if that was intended but thanks! :)

Comment: @PeterToole glad to help! If this answer assisted you, please accept it.

Answer (score 7):

The fundamental problem here is that you need to split the message into separate parts that can be decoded separately.

A message is first separated by slashes (words), and then by spaces (characters). So we can use `split()` twice here to obtain the elements:

```
for word in message.split('/'):
    for character in word.strip().split():
        # ... decode the character
```

Now we thus need something to decode the character. But storing a dictionary with characters as keys does not make much sense: we want to decode the message, so here the dots and hyphens need to be the keys, not the alphabet characters.

We can build a new dictionary ourselves, or construct a new dictionary automatically:

```
decode_dict = {v: k for k, v in alphabet.items()}
```

So then we can use a lookup approach:

```
decode_dict = {v: k for k, v in alphabet.items()}

for word in message.split('/'):
    for character in word.strip().split():
        print(decode_dict[character])  # print the decoded character
    print(' ')  # print space after the word
```

Now we obtain the decoded message, but with every character on a separate line. We can however use `str.join` and generators to generate a string first:

```
' '.join(''.join(decode_dict[character] for character in word.strip().split())
         for word in message.split('/'))
```

The outcome then is the decoded string:

```
>>> ' '.join(''.join(decode_dict[character] for character in word.strip().split())
...          for word in message.split('/'))
'WHERE ARE YOU'
```

Comment: When I do that for some reason it prints "Where are you" many times am I doing this wrong, can you edit that response with the final code?

Comment: I managed to get it right, but the decoded message is outputting with each character on a new line

Comment: @PeterToole, to get it not to output each character on a new line, use `print(message, end='')`

Comment: @PeterToole: but it is already in the answer. You should not always print every decoded character, you better join the content together.